# what is the initial temperature of the object?

Tags: arithmetic

I have a question and I cant solve it . I'll be thankful if you solve it for me and give your complete solution.

We put an object in a freezer which have -17 degrees temperature. After a few minutes The object's temperature reduced by 30.What is the initial temperature of the object?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what does this have to do with NT ?

Comment: You don't have enough information to determine the initial temperature. Also, you should mention what physics model/assumptions you want to use. Also, the tag is wrong.

Comment: I didn't know what tag I should use you can see the answer others given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial temperature is greater or equal to +13 degrees ;)

Comment: How did you solve it? Would you please post your solution?

Comment: @AmirrezaFiroozi: $13 = -17 + 30$